# Query ya no funciona en Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Estoy trabajando en una base de datos con información acerca de cursos y creé una query para saber cuántos cursos vendía cada vendedor al mes. Esta es la query:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW tblStudentCourses.SalesID, Format$([tblStudentCourses].[SignDate],'mmmm yyyy') AS [SignDate By Month], Sum(tblStudentCourses.Fee) AS [Sum Of Fee], Avg(tblStudentCourses.Fee) AS [Avg Of Fee], Count(*) AS [Count Of tblStudentCourses]
FROM tblStudentCourses
GROUP BY tblStudentCourses.SalesID, Format$([tblStudentCourses].[SignDate],'mmmm yyyy'), Year([tblStudentCourses].[SignDate])*12+DatePart('m',[tblStudentCourses].[SignDate])-1;
```

Funcionó sin problemas hasta hoy en que me arroja error de sintaxis con esta parte **Format$([tblStudentCourses].[SignDate],'mmmm yyyy'** No he cambiado ningún parámetro ni relación en la tabla.

¿Alguien me podría decir porqué dejó de funcionar y cómo arreglarlo?

Gracias :)

Comment: ¿Configuración regional?

Comment: Hola Paula, por favor lee [ask] y [answer] y completa el [tour] par ver cómo funciona el sitio en general.

Answer (score 0):

Como recomendación general para trabajar con fechas, deberías hacerlo en [formato canónico (ISO 8601)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) yyyymmdd. Dependiendo como accedas al MDB, debería revisar la configuración del driver, ODBC, configuración regional del sistema operativo...

Habitualmente una fecha 12/12/2018 puede funcionar pero de manera incorrecta al pasar a 12/13/2018 o 13/12/2018 según donde situe el mes

Además el tratamiento puede diferir de [Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-the-date-and-time-field-in-access-47fbbdc1-52fa-416a-b8d5-ba24d881b698) a [SQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms180878(v=sql.105).aspx), especialmente con fechas, internamente deberias procurar hacer las comparaciones numéricas y no por texto.

Es más eficiente y menos problemático operar con 201803 para marzo de 2018 que hacerlo en "marzo 2018"